# Emacs global-set-key in find-file

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings

In my `init.el` file I have this:

```lisp
(global-set-key "\M-n" (lambda () (interactive) (insert "~")))
```

This allows me to use <kbd>Alt-n</kbd> on my Mac to produce the `~` character. It works fine in buffers etc. but when I try to use it in `find-file` I get

> "End of history no default available".

<kbd>C-h k</kbd> reveals that <kbd>M-n</kbd> actually calls:

```
(lambda nil (interactive) (insert "~"))
```

Why doesn't this work with `find-file`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global key bindings are overridden by local (i.e., major-mode) key bindings, which are overridden by minor-mode bindings, which are overridden by... IOW, there are lots of *levels* of key binding.

In this case, your global binding is overridden by a minibuffer keymap binding.

In the minibuffer completion keymaps, which are local maps, `M-n` is bound to `next-history-element`.  If you want `M-n` in such a map to be bound to something else, then you need to bind it. For example:

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map "\M-n" 'your-command)
```

There are several minibuffer completion keymaps, depending on your Emacs version.  The two main ones are `minibuffer-local-completion-map` and `minibuffer-local-must-match-map`.